# Gnome Terminal - button to run command

Tags: scripting, gnome, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to create a button (attached to the Terminal in Gnome) that runs a command in the current Terminal window?

Just being lazy really but rather than typing out `terraform init`, `terraform plan` over and over again, it would be really handy if there was a button I could click that would simply run one of those commands.

Comment: Anything is possible as long as you have the right skills... If you're proficient with `c`, `gtk+` you could alter [`gnome-terminal`](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal) source code and add a button that does that... For the people who are "just being lazy" I'd recommend an alias though...

Comment: I would rather try to add a key alias / hotkey to enter a string a of text in the current window, whatever it is. These tools exist.

Comment: @Ned64 The problem with a key alias is it's yet another thing to remember. A button is way easier.

Comment: Well, you could put a sticker on an F- or other special key. But better (easier) yet ...

Answer (score 1):

Make a shell alias, that is much, much easier than changing gnome-terminal's GUI (as there is no option for it, you would need to code it):

Assuming you are using `bash`, put the following into `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ti='terraform init'
alias tp='terraform plan'
```

If you use `tcsh` the equivalent would be

```
alias ti 'terraform init'
alias tp 'terraform plan'
```

in your `~/.tcshrc` (ideally in a section that is excluded in non-interactive mode).

After installing these aliases and starting a new shell you can type these aliases with many fewer keystrokes than the whole command.

Also easier than typing the whole command would be to use your commandline history. One can search backward in the previously entered commands for those that start with letters.  In `bash` you can start backwards search in history with `Ctrl+r`, then start typing and using cursor keys `Up`/`Down`.  In `tcsh` this is a litte easier, just type the first few letters (e.g. `te`), then search for previous/next command lines starting with the letters entered, by pressing `Alt+p`/`Alt+n`.